# Two Page Form Submits On First Page

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, phpmailer

I am trying to create a two page form- the first page is optional. Its a prompt to get started. It was working perfectly until I started adding in PHPMailer. Now when I click submit on the first, optional form on the first page it submits it through the mailer and all its validations/errors then emails correctly it if I comment out the error if statements.

Here is the first form that is optional. It should take you to the estimate page with those values stored in the form already so you don't have to do it over again.

```
   <form class="form-horizontal first-form" action="estimate.php"              method="post">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputMoveDate" class="col-xs-4 text-left">Move Date</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control" id="datepicker">
                    </div><!--col-xs-7-->
                  </div><!--form-group-->
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pickUpZip" class="col-xs-4">Pick Up Zip</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                      <input type="text" name="pickUpZip" class="form-control" id="pickUpZip" placeholder="">
                    </div><!--col-xs-7-->
                  </div><!--form-group-->
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="dropOffZip" class="col-xs-4">Drop Off Zip</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                      <input type="text" name="dropOffZip" class="form-control" id="dropOffZip" placeholder="">
                    </div><!--col-xs-7-->
                  </div><!--form-group-->
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default center-block">Continue</button>
                    </div><!--col-sm-offset-2-->
                  </div><!--form-group-->
                </form>
```

Estimate.php second page. The PHP at the top of the document.

```
session_start();

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $pickUpZip = $_POST['pickUpZip'];
    $dropOffZip = $_POST['dropOffZip'];
    $dwellingType = $_POST['dwellingType'];
    $salutation = $_POST['salutation'];
    $firstName = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "first-name", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    $lastName = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "last-name", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    $email = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email", FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS));
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $pickUpAddress = $_POST['pickUpAddress'];
    $pickUpCity = $_POST['pickUpCity'];
    $pickUpState = $_POST['pickUpState'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];

    $emailBody ="From: $salutation $firstName $lastName\n 
        Phone Number: $phone\n
        E-Mail: $email\n 
        Message:\n $comments
        \n \n
        Move Date: $date\n
        Pick Up Address: $pickUpAddress\n
        Pick Up City: $pickUpCity\n
        Pick Up State: $pickUpState\n
        Pick Up Zip: $pickUpZip\n
        \n
        Drop Off Zip: $dropOffZip\n
        Dwelling Type: $dwellingType\n";

    if($firstName == "" || $email == "" || $lastName == "") {
        echo "Please fill in the required forms: first name, last name, and email.";
        exit;
    }
    if ($_POST["address"] != "") {
        echo "Bad form input";
        exit;
    }

    require('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    if (!$mail->ValidateAddress($email)) {
        echo 'Invalid email. Try again.';
        exit;
    }

    $mail->setFrom($email, $firstName);
    $mail->addAddress('xxxx@xxx.com', 'name here');

    $mail->isHTML(false);

    $mail->Subject = 'Estimate Request Inquiry From ' . $firstName;
    $mail->Body    = $emailBody;

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        exit;
    }

    header("location:estimate.php?status=thanks");
}
```

Here is the starting and ending of the form HTML, the highlights.

```
         <?PHP 
            if (isset($_GET["status"]) && $_GET["status"] == "thanks") {
                echo "Thank you for your estimate request. We will return your inquiry soon!
            </div>";
            } else {
                        ?>
   <form class="form-horizontal first-form" action="estimate.php" method="post" style="margin: 0 45px;">
```

```
         <label for="date" class="col-xs-4 text-left">Move Date</label>
                                <div class="col-xs-8">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker" name="date" value="<?php echo $_POST["date"]; ?>">
                                </div><!--col-xs-7-->
                              </div><!--form-group-->
                              <div class="form-group">
              <label for="pickUpZip" class="col-xs-4">Pick Up Zip</label>
                                <div class="col-xs-8">
                                  <input type="text" name="pickUpZip" class="form-control" id="pickUpZip" value="<?php echo $_POST["pickUpZip"]; ?>">
                                </div><!--col-xs-7-->
                              </div><!--form-group-->

                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="dropOffZip" class="col-xs-4">Drop Off Zip</label>
                                <div class="col-xs-8">
                                  <input type="text" name="dropOffZip" class="form-control" id="dropOffZip" value="<?php echo $_POST["dropOffZip"]; ?>">
                                </div><!--col-xs-7-->
                              </div><!--form-group-->

                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                  <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default center-block">Submit</button>
                                </div><!--col-sm-offset-2-->
                              </div><!--form-group-->
                            </form>
                            <?PHP
                                }
                            ?>
```

Comment: You are just checking `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {` on your second page, and you are posting from  your first page so it believes you are making the final submission, there are several ways to solve this, one would be to add a hidden field on the first form and then check to make sure that doesn't exist on the second page before running your validation code.

Comment: This makes sense to me. I am trying to make it work by having an if statement "if this hidden element remains blank then do all this. Basically wrapping everything else this if statement while having not blank give an error and exit. It is not working so far. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This line attempts to send the email every time:

```
if(!$mail->send()) {
```

and your error messages are echoed if and when it fails.
You should nest this entire block in an if statement that checks if the form was submitted from page 2. You can give the submit button a different value and check that (i.e. 'submit1', 'submit2').

Comment: What kind of if statement? Sorry I'm a real beginner. Thing is, the first form is entirely optional and not necessary so that's where I'm struggling with how to continue passing those values if they are there but if not, wait for the second form's submission.